# Waiting for reference checks. How to proceed?

Tags: references

I went through 3 interview steps, and then HR called me and told me that they want to proceed with my application. They asked from me 3 references. I've provided 4.

The thing is that it was urgent for them. And they asked to send references as soon as possible. I've checked they have contacted only to 2 references that are my direct managers and now it's a week they didn't call me. I would understand this if it is not urgent. But they have told me when I need to start and I don't have much time for giving a notice to my current employer.

I guess at some point I need to contact the HR but when and how to ask so I don't sound pushy.

Can you please help?

Bruce

Comment: Note that not every organization checks every reference.  They want the references so that they _can_ check them, not necessarily that they will check all of them.

Comment: Thanks Jane. What about waiting? How long should I wait before contacting them considering that they were going to make an urgent placement? I'm thinking to call them next week, but I don't want to look pushy at the same time. This is job is life changing for me and I want to handle it professionally

Comment: It is reasonable to contact HR a week afterward to check on the progress of your application.  I would suggest looking at [this thread](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's been a week, it's perfectly acceptable to email your HR contact. Here is a sample:

> Hi [insert contact's name],
>
> I enjoyed interviewing with [insert company's name] on [insert interview data]. I am really excited about this opportunity and I was wondering when I will hear back on next steps?
>
> Thank you, [insert your name]

Remember to be polite and reiterate your excitement to join the company.

Comment: Thanks, wrote the message and got prompt response that they are waiting for the approval and hopefully they will have an update by the end of the week, which is tomorrow. Is it possible that they already have refusal but keep delaying in hope that I'll disappear myself? The position was urgent

Comment: @WBruce Hard to tell, but remember to keep interviewing!

Comment: I know, but the problem that I don't have time. The opportunity is in different city and I've already canceled my current rental lease. Long story short, my family is growing. If I rent anything new, I'll be stuck for another year in my current city.